# asdoc error "Too many nested template or function calls"

Tags: apache-flex, asdoc

```
[asdoc] ���ڼ��������ļ���D:\4.5.0\frameworks\flex-config.xml��
[asdoc] Error at xsl:call-template on line 310 of fieldSummary.xslt:
[asdoc]   Too many nested template or function calls. The stylesheet may be looping.
[asdoc] Transformation failed: Run-time errors were reported
```

Comment: Clearly ASDoc is failing to run citing too many tested template or function calls.  They are trying to resolve the error to generate documentation.  This question could be written better.

Answer (score 0):

When ASDoc fails, there is usually a more descriptive citation of the error within log file.

At the end of that error message is likely a path to the log, in which it will explicitly state errors in greater details.  It will state something such as:

> Please see C:\flex\bin\framework-asdoc\validation_errors.log for
>   details.

Comment: no,i can't find the error log, reported the error ,Error at xsl:call-template on line 310 of fieldSummary.xslt: